# Globally handling errors in Nuxt 3 SSR and suppressing certain errors

Tags: error-handling, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I want to globally handle all errors, but display `error.vue` only for 404. For other errors i want to display a modal on page load. So the page should be rendered, regardless of errors other than 404.
In `./plugins/errorHandling.ts` i do this:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(app => {
    const storeModals = useStoreModals();
    app.hook('app:error', (error: NuxtError<unknown> | null | undefined) => {
        if (error?.statusCode === 404)
            return;
        console.error(error);
        storeModals.alert500(); // this way i change the state to have an error and show it after the page is loaded
        clearError(); // this doesn't seem to do anything
    });
}
```

Then i throw an error with **createError** in one of my components. But i still get the page from `error.vue` (which is responsible only for 404 in my case).